# How to add parameters to a @Url.Action() call from JavaScript on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a link that when clicked needs to call a controller action with certain data which must be retrieved via JavaScript.  The action will be returning a FileStreamResult.

I looked at @Url.Action but I couldn't figure out how (or even if) I could pass value dictionary stuff which had to be retrieved via JS.

So then I went with a $.post from a click handler.  The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure what to do in my success: function() to return the file stream result to the user.  Or even if I can.

So any help on how you would do something like this would be great..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So then I went with a $.post from a click handler. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure what to do in my success: function() to return the file stream result to the user. Or even if I can.

Exactly. You can't do much with a received byte in javascritpt: obviously you cannot save it on the client computer nor pass it to some external program on the client. So don't call actions that are supposed to return files using AJAX. For those actions you should use normal links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("download file", "download", new { id = 123 })
```

and let the user decide what to do with the file. You could play with the `Content-Disposition` header and set it to either `inline` or `attachment` depending on whether you want the file to be opened with the default associated program inside the browser or prompt the user with a Save File dialog.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that I have misunderstood the question. If you want to append parameters to an existing link you could subscribe for the click event in javascript and modify the href by appending the necessary parameters to the query string:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        var someValue = 'value of parameter';
        $(this).attr('href', this.href + '?paramName=' + encodeURIComponent(someValue));
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Obviously you missed the part where I mentioned I have can't figure out HOW to have a normal link yet still gather some information for the call via Javascript?

Comment: @ShaneC, yes indeed, I have missed that part. Well, it's easy, simply subscribe for the click event of the link and append them as query string parameters to the current href and return true to allow the default behavior.

Comment: @ShaneC, I've updated my answer to illustrate my comment with a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the actual title so that it's more search friendly for others since such your answer was so elegant for a problem I'm sure is common amongst newbies :)

Comment: @ShaneC, if this post helped you solve the issue maybe you could mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with a post, I'd go with associate a JQuery on click handler of the link which would call the controller action. This is assuming that the action method returns a FileStreamResult and sets the correct content type so that the browser interprets the result and renders it accordingly.

With your approach you'd have to interpret in the onSuccessHandler of the post on how to render the generated stream.